# func (rs *Rows) Scan to handle a column type of array string

Tags: postgresql, go

I have a column within my Postgres db for tags which is an array of strings.

I have it defined within a struct in my golang as:

```
type device struct {
    deviceID   string
    macAddress sql.NullString
    name       sql.NullString
    agentID    sql.NullString
    groupType  sql.NullString
    tags       []string

    normalized           bool
    normalizedName       string
    normalizedMacAddress string
}
```

When I run the scan on the rows as such:

```
            err = rows.Scan(&d.deviceID, &d.name, &d.tags, &d.macAddress, &d.agentID, &d.groupType)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
```

It returns the following error:

```
"sql: Scan error on column index 2, name "tags": unsupported Scan...+55 more"
```

So what kinda of wrapper do I need for a string array in order to be an acceptable type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [pq.Array](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#Array) when scanning an array:

```
    err = rows.Scan(&d.deviceID, &d.name, pq.Array(&d.tags), &d.macAddress, &d.agentID, &d.groupType)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Comment: would I need to change my original struct def?

Comment: No.  Just call the function as shown in the answer.